# Setup dual monitors with my laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have two questions.

First: I have one laptop and two monitors. I would like to extend display on the two monitors.

**Laptop**: HP ZBOOK15-G3 running Windows 7 Professional (http://store.hp.com/us/en/mdp/business-solutions/zbook-15-mobile-workstation-243552--1?jumpid=cp_r11400_us/en/ips/business_laptops/workstation/buynowZ15G3)
Left side: 1 VGA; 1 USB 3.0 (charging)
Right side: 2 USB Type-C™ (Thunderbolt™ 3, DP 1.2, USB 3.1); 1 HDMI 1.4; 2 USB 3.0;

**Monitor 1**: NEC MultiSync EA223WM
Interfaces: DVI-D, DisplayPort, USB 2.0 downstream, USB 2.0 upstream, VGA

**Monitor 2**: Samsung SyncMaster 2443
Interfaces: 15 pin HD D-Sub (HD-15), 24 pin digital DVI, 4 pin USB Type A

What economic option/s do I have to extend display on the two monitors besides using a docking station? 
If so, what cables/gadgets do I need?

Second: I would also like to add more USB ports to my laptop (currently only 3) if that's possible, what solutions are there?

FYI, I am not a hardware guy and I am lost with all these "standards". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack won't let me post more than two links. Here are the links to the spec. of the monitors:
**Monitor 1**: NEC MultiSync EA223WM (https://www.cnet.com/products/nec-multisync-ea223wm-bk-led-monitor-22/specs/)  

**Monitor 2**: Samsung SyncMaster 2443 (https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-syncmaster-2243bw-lcd-monitor-22/specs/)

Comment: In regards to your second question, to add USB ports, you'd have to wire new USB ports to the motherboard and cut rectangles out of the chassis, which is quite tedious. Instead, you can use a USB hub/dock/splitter, which can connect 4+ USB devices at one time, and plugs into 1 USB port on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a VGA port, your best bet for the second display is a USB-based video graphics adapter such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KB5IHGS).

Regarding additional USB ports, the simple solution is a USB hub.

Comment: Thanks. Since both my monitors support DVI, is it possible to connect my laptop to both monitors using DVI? If so, what gadget do I need?

Comment: Well, you could simply buy two of the above devices. Dedicated VGA to DVI adapters exist such as this one - - https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=8214 - - but as you can see, they are a bit pricey. Honestly, though, for short runs (desktop) you are extremely unlikely to see any difference between the VGA connected monitor and the DVI connected monitor, other than normal differences due to monitor manufacturing.

Comment: Thanks again. But would something like this work? https://www.amazon.com/External-Graphics-Converter-Multiple-Monitors/dp/B011BQ6X2U

Comment: Yes. That would work.